# std::map of string and regex

Tags: c++, regex, string, c++11, macros

I'm working on a C++ project where a small language is implemented. In fact, the main consists on a kind of "pseudo-instructions" where I use the preprocessor to translate them into valid C++ code. This project is an assignment from a course and the code in main has to be in that format.

This is part of the line in the main.cpp:

```
PROGRAM_START

REGEX(name): START TEXT(a) TEXT(b) END  //TEXT(a) TEXT(b) gives the string "ab"
.
.
//more regex definitions here
.
.

PROGRAM_END
```

and on the .h file I have:

```
std::map<std::string, std::regex> regex_map;
std::string regex_name;

#define PROGRAM_BEGIN int main(){
#define PROGRAM_END   return 0;}

#define REGEX(name) \
std::regex name; \
regex_map[#name] = name; \       //exception here
(1) ? (regex_name = #name) \

#define START (regex_name = ""); \

#define END \   regex_map.find(regex_name)->second.assign(currStr,std::regex::ECMAScript); \

#define TEXT(a)  getRegex(#a);
...
```

I want to create a map containing the regex and the string representing the regex's name but the string that would be the value of the regex isn't known until we reach `END`. 
So I want to insert a pair in the map with an empty regex on the `REGEX(name)` macro and then on the `END` macro, by using the regex's name to find the pair on the map, I want to assign the string to the regex.

But even though the project is built just fine, on the line I show above I get an exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x0097171F in (project name).exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Any idea why this happens and how I can achieve what I want to do?

**NOTE:** `getRegex(#a)` isn't important in this case. Creates an instance of some class I have made and gives value to the string currStr.

**NOTE2:** The use of the ternary operator is just for supporting the ":" character in the main.

Comment: I think you'd need to build a fully working example for us to see what's going on here. Also, can you not find a better way to do what you want to do than use MACROS?

Comment: `Access violation reading location 0x00000000` means you're trying to dereference a `nullptr` somewhere, but we won't be able to tell you more than that without a *full* example. Also, for the macros, you'd have to post the full thing so we can see if there's a better alternative.

Comment: What, if any, is the connection between `name` and `regex_name`?

Comment: @Galik I'm afraid the use of the preprocessor is necessary for this assignment.
@IgorTandetnik I use the `regex_name` string to store the name given to the regex so I can assign the resulting string `currStr` to it when I reach `END`

Comment: another wonderful BS c++ assignment

Comment: Much of what you posted isn't legal, doesn't compile.

Comment: I have no problem with the compilation, although there is certainly sth wrong with the code. So how can I make the map with what I want work?

Comment: There's no need to pre-create the regex. Use `map`'s emplace member function: `regex_map.emplace("name", "a*b+");`. Or, if you prefer, use the fact that the `[]` operator automatically adds the key with a default constructed value type, so you can say `regex_map["name"] = "a*b+";` even if `"name"` was not previously in the `map`.